# Get line that matches regex in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, regex

I have a long list of information stored in a variable and I need to run some regex expressions against that variable and get various pieces of information from what is found.

1. How can you store the line that matches a regex expression in a variable?
2. How can you get the line number of the line that matches a regex expression?

Here is an example of what I'm talking about.

body = "service timestamps log datetime msec localtime show-timezone
service password-encryption
!
hostname switch01
!
boot-start-marker"

If I search for the line that contains "hostname" I need the line number, in this case it would be 4.  I also need to store the line "hostname switch01" as another variable.

Any ideas?

Thanks!

Comment: What is a line in your example? How do you know to stop after `switch01` ?

Answer (score 1):

First you'd want to convert the string to lines: `body.split('\n')`, then you want to add line numbers to the lines: `.each_with_index`. Then you want to select the lines `.select {|line, line_nr| line =~ your_regex }`. Putting it all together:

```
body.split('\n').each_with_index
                .select {|line, line_nr| line =~ your_regex }
                .map {|line, line_nr| line_nr }
```

This will give you all the lines matching 'your_regex'

Answer (score 1):

Let's say you have an object `file` that provides a `#lines` method:

```
lines = file.lines.each_with_index.select {|line, i| line =~ /regex/ }
```

If you already have a list of lines you can leave out the call to `#lines`. If you have a string you can use `string.split("\n")`.
This will result in the variable `lines` containing an array of 2-element arrays with the line that matched your RegEx and the index of the line in the original file.

## Breakdown

`file.lines` gets the lines - of course the other methods I mentioned might also apply here for you. We then add the index to each element with `#each_with_index`, because you want to store these as well. This has the same effect as `#map.with_index {|e, i| [e, i]}`, i.e. map every element to `[element, index]`. We then use the `#select` method to get all lines that do match your RegEx (FYI, `=~` is the matching operator in Ruby, Perl and other languages - in case you didn't already know). We're done after that, but you might need to further transform the data so you can process it.